# Multiple Cursors in Sublime Text 2 Windows

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have installed Sublime Text 2 in windows and I am trying to use the multiple cursors feature.

Firstly I highlight the selection I am looking for (three lines).

Then I can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to select each re-occurrence, or <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> to select all. There are four repeats in my situation.

I now want to move the cursors in the middle of the three lines and add some information, to be added to all occurrences.

As soon as I click in the selection, the multiple selection is gone? Is there something I am doing wrong, I am sure it is wrong but as the documentation is so weak I cannot find out how?

Comment: Does  `ctrl+shift+l` give you multiple cursors?

Comment: Landed here looking for this: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/column_selection.html

Comment: Damn I'll need a better mouse for this. Thanks twamley

Comment: `Ctrl + left click` was the solution for me. See answer of Zenexer for much more.

Comment: Thanks twamley; love it when purposes collide on SO.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In Sublime Text, after you select multiple regions of text, a click is considered a way to exit the multi-select mode. Move the cursor with the keyboard keys (arrows, Ctrl+arrows, etc.) instead, and you'll be fine

Comment: ctrl+shift+l - also. Thanks

Comment: I have to say I find this one of the drawbacks of Sublime, never had to click myself out of trouble in others or use key combos, depending on the situation. Some situations expect you to press Enter. What's wrong with Esc? :)

Answer (score 162):

It's usually just easier to skip the mouse altogether--or it would be if Sublime didn't mess up multiselect when word wrapping.  Here's the official documentation on using the [keyboard](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html) and [mouse](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/selection) for multiple selection.  Since it's a bit spread out, I'll summarize it:

Where shortcuts are different in Sublime Text 3, I've made a note.  For v3, I always test using the latest dev build; if you're using the beta build, your experience may be different.

If you lose your selection when switching tabs or windows (particularly on Linux), try using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> to restore it.

## Mouse

### Windows/Linux

Building blocks:

- Positive/negative:

  - Add to selection: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
  - Subtract from selection: <kbd>Alt</kbd> *In early builds of v3, this didn't work for linear selection.*
- Selection type:

  - Linear selection: <kbd>Left Click</kbd>
  - Block selection: <kbd>Middle Click</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Click</kbd>  *On Linux, middle click pastes instead by default.*

Combine as you see fit.  For example:

- Add to selection: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd> (and optionally drag)
- Subtract from selection: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd> *This didn't work in early builds of v3.*
- Add block selection: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Click</kbd> (and drag)
- Subtract block selection: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Click</kbd> (and drag)

### Mac OS X

Building blocks:

- Positive/negative:

  - Add to selection: <kbd>⌘</kbd>
  - Subtract from selection: <kbd>⇧⌘</kbd> (only works with block selection in v3; presumably bug)
- Selection type:

  - Linear selection: <kbd>Left Click</kbd>
  - Block selection: <kbd>Middle Click</kbd> or <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd>

Combine as you see fit.  For example:

- Add to selection: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd> (and optionally drag)
- Subtract from selection: <kbd>⇧⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd> (and drag--this combination doesn't work in Sublime Text 3, but supposedly it works in 2)
- Add block selection: <kbd>⌥⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd> (and drag)
- Subtract block selection: <kbd>⌥⇧⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd> (and drag)

## Keyboard

### Windows

- Return to single selection mode: <kbd>Esc</kbd>
- Extend selection upward/downward at all carets: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>
- Extend selection leftward/rightward at all carets: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>
- Move all carets up/down/left/right, and clear selection: <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>/<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>
- Undo the last selection motion: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>
- Add next occurrence of selected text to selection: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
- Add all occurrences of the selected text to the selection: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>
- Rotate between occurrences of selected text (single selection): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> (reverse: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>)
- Turn a single linear selection into a block selection, with a caret at the end of the selected text in each line: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

### Linux

- Return to single selection mode: <kbd>Esc</kbd>
- Extend selection upward/downward at all carets: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>  *Note that you may be able to hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as well to get the same shortcuts as Windows, but Linux tends to use Ctrl + Alt combinations for global shortcuts.*
- Extend selection leftward/rightward at all carets: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>
- Move all carets up/down/left/right, and clear selection: <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>/<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>
- Undo the last selection motion: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>
- Add next occurrence of selected text to selection: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
- Add all occurrences of the selected text to the selection: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>
- Rotate between occurrences of selected text (single selection): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> (reverse: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>)
- Turn a single linear selection into a block selection, with a caret at the end of the selected text in each line: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

### Mac OS X

- Return to single selection mode: <kbd>⎋</kbd> (that's the Mac symbol for Escape)
- Extend selection upward/downward at all carets: <kbd>⌃⇧⇡</kbd>, <kbd>⌃⇧⇣</kbd> (See note)
- Extend selection leftward/rightward at all carets: <kbd>⇧⇠</kbd>/<kbd>⇧⇢</kbd>
- Move all carets up/down/left/right and clear selection: <kbd>⇠</kbd>, <kbd>⇡</kbd>, <kbd>⇣</kbd>, <kbd>⇢</kbd>
- Undo the last selection motion: <kbd>⌘U</kbd>
- Add next occurrence of selected text to selection: <kbd>⌘D</kbd>
- Add all occurrences of the selected text to the selection: <kbd>⌃⌘G</kbd>
- Rotate between occurrences of selected text (single selection): <kbd>⌥⌘G</kbd> (reverse: <kbd>⌥⇧⌘G</kbd>)
- Turn a single linear selection into a block selection, with a caret at the end of the selected text in each line: <kbd>⇧⌘L</kbd>

#### Notes for Mac users

On Yosemite and El Capitan, <kbd>⌃⇧⇡</kbd> and <kbd>⌃⇧⇣</kbd> are system keyboard shortcuts by default.  If you want them to work in Sublime Text, you will need to change them:

1. Open `System Preferences`.
2. Select the `Shortcuts` tab.
3. Select `Mission Control` in the left listbox.
4. Change the keyboard shortcuts for `Mission Control` and `Application windows` (or disable them).  I use <kbd>⌃⌥⇡</kbd> and <kbd>⌃⌥⇣</kbd>.  They defaults are <kbd>⌃⇡</kbd> and <kbd>⌃⇣</kbd>; adding <kbd>⌃</kbd> to those shortcuts triggers the same actions, but slows the animations.

In case you're not familiar with Mac's keyboard symbols:

- <kbd>⎋</kbd> is the escape key
- <kbd>⌃</kbd> is the control key
- <kbd>⌥</kbd> is the option key
- <kbd>⇧</kbd> is the shift key
- <kbd>⌘</kbd> is the command key
- <kbd>⇡</kbd> et al are the arrow keys, as depicted

Comment: I came here looking for the issue that, as @Zenexer says, Sublime messes up multiselect when word wrapping is on. I have that all the time: Select a block for manual indenting (`Alt` click-drag) - if word wrap is on, lines will be damaged when indenting them. Is that a known bug? `⇧⌘L` seems to perform better.

Comment: Just asking, but is there a way to remap those in sublime preferences? If so what are the JSON options for that? I am unable to find documentation for that.

Comment: @Hans _Preferences_ -> _Key Bindings_ -> search for shortcuts on the left side, copy them to the right side, edit. See also [Key Bindings](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/key_bindings.html) in the Sublime docs. Just in case you have not figured it out after 4,5 years :-)

Answer (score 13):

Try using Ctrl-click on the multiple places you want the cursors. Ctrl-D is for multiple incremental finds.

Comment: This is what I was hoping to find. It's `cmd + click` on a Mac to insert multiple cursors wherever you want.

Answer (score 3):

I find using vintage mode works really well with sublime multiselect.

My most used keys would be "w" for jumping a word, "^" and "$" to move to first/last character  of the line. Combinations like "2dw" (delete the next two words after the cursor) make using multiselect really powerful.

This sounds obvious but has really sped up my workflow, especially when editing HTML.

Comment: vim makes me feel more productive, but I'm not sure that I'm actually faster with it.

Answer (score 1):

Mac Users, let me save you the time:

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>: select the lines you want a cursor
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>: to create the cursor